# How to access a property which is hidden for another property in a child class?

Tags: delphi, oop

I'm writing a [`TCustomDBGrid`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid) descendent component which need to access the protected property Options([`TGridOptions`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TGridOptions)), which is part of the parent class ([`TCustomGrid`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid)) of the [TCustomDBGrid](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid) object. the issue is which exist a property with the same name *reintroduced* in the `TCustomDBGrid` class but with another type ([TDBGridOptions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGridOptions)).

Check simplified this declaration

```
 TCustomGrid=  = class(TCustomControl)
 protected
  //I need to access this property
  property Options: TGridOptions read FOptions write SetOptions
      default [goFixedVertLine, goFixedHorzLine, goVertLine, goHorzLine,
      goRangeSelect];
 end;

  TCustomDBGrid = class(TCustomGrid)
  protected
    //a property with the same name is reintroduced in this class
    property Options: TDBGridOptions read FOptions write SetOptions
      default [dgEditing, dgTitles, dgIndicator, dgColumnResize, dgColLines,
      dgRowLines, dgTabs, dgConfirmDelete, dgCancelOnExit, dgTitleClick, dgTitleHotTrack];   
  end;


  TDBGridEx = class(TCustomDBGrid)
  protected
    //inside of this method I need to access the property TCustomGrid.Options
    procedure FastDraw(ACol, ARow: Longint; ARect: TRect; AState: TGridDrawState);
  end;
```

I figured out how access this property using a cracker class.

```
type
  TCustomGridClass=class(TCustomGrid);

{ TDBGridEx }
procedure TDBGridEx.FastDraw(ACol, ARow: Integer; ARect: TRect; AState: TGridDrawState);
var
 LOptions: TGridOptions;
 LRect : TRect;
begin
  ......
  LOptions := TCustomGridClass(Self).Options; //works fine
  LRect := ARect;
  if not (goFixedVertLine in LOptions) then
    Inc(LRect.Right);
  if not (goFixedHorzLine in LOptions) then
    Inc(LRect.Bottom);
  .....
end;
```

But **just for curiosity** I'm wondering if exist another workaround or a better way for resolve this.

Comment: This is the only workaround I've ever seen for this type situation. I'd be surprised if there's another solution, but +1 for the well-written question. :-)

Comment: would be very nice write something like `LOptions := inherited TCustomGrid  Options;` :)

Comment: It would, except that would make `protected` mean nothing. :-) If you wanted that, everything would be `private`, `public` or `published`, and they could remove the `protected` visibility; I don't think that's what I'd want. :-)

Comment: I would seriously think of redesigning the component if it needs to access a hidden property. I guess where is no a better hack to solve your problem.

Comment: @RRUZ using a cracker class *is* the only way to do it; make your solution an answer (: I like your language extension idea, can you QC that?

Comment: @Serg: normally I'd agree with you. But in this case the need doesn't arise from the component being designed but from its ancestor(s). The VCL isn't exactly extension-friendly. Many methods and properties have lower visibility than helpful for extending controls, and many methods that could be used for a clean extension design, are not marked virtual.

Comment: @Marjan:  Especially with the grids and buttons in the VCL, I find it's better to start from scratch than to inherit from any of the grid or button controls in the VCL.

Comment: @WarrenP: yes, but not everybody wants to invest the time and effort needed to do that. While a GUI is important, I'd rather invest scarce resources in building business logic than in re-inventing a control for the sake of a clean design if all I need is a couple of tweaks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another workaround using `class helpers`.  It is not as good hack as yours but works.

```
type
  TCustomGridHelper = class helper for TCustomGrid
    function GetGridOptions: TGridOptions;
  end;

function TCustomGridHelper.GetGridOptions: TGridOptions;
begin
  Result := Self.Options;
end;

procedure TDBGridEx.FastDraw(ACol, ARow: Integer; ARect: TRect;
  AState: TGridDrawState);
var
 LOptions: TGridOptions;
 LRect : TRect;
begin
  ...
  LOptions := Self.GetGridOptions; //works fine
  ...
end;
```